# Nested Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nested

Can someone tell me how I can create a nested table in SQL Server and how can I used it?

I know it on Oracle, unfortunately not on SQL Server...

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175659(v=sql.110).aspx), it is possible for SQL Server 2012 to have Nested Table but this is related to Data Mining which I am not sure of.